# nginx multiple domains (www and non-www for each domain)

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to host two domains on an nginx server, with www to non-www redirection. Here are my site configs:

**site 1:**

```
server {
    root /var/www/afspraken/;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name site1.nl;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
server {
    server_name www.site1.nl;
    return 301 $scheme://site1.nl$request_uri;
}
```

**site 2:**

```
server {
    root /var/www/mijn/;
    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name site2.nl;
}
server {
        server_name www.site2.nl;
        return 301 $scheme://site2.nl$request_uri;
}
```

Three of the four servers work correctly: `www.site2.nl`, `site2.nl` and `site1.nl`. The `www.site1.nl` server gives me site2 though. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. The servers that return 301 need to be defined first (before the servers that actually handle the redirected requests). Working example:

```
server {
        server_name www.mijnbedrijfook.nl;
        return 301 $scheme://mijnbedrijfook.nl$request_uri;
}
server {
    root /var/www/mijn/;
    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name mijnbedrijfook.nl;
}
```